# Get FIle extension using Android Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, mediastore, storage-access-framework

I am using the Storage Access Framework in android for selecting images and uploading in my app. Before uploading these images to my server, i also process these images (resizing).
However, in the URI returned by the  SAF, there is no extension appended, i don't know how to get extension of the file. I need to differentiate between png and jpeg. How can i achieve that ?
Example uri returned from SAF - `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A245309`

My code is something like this

```
if (resultData != null) {
                        final ClipData clipData = resultData.getClipData();
                        int takeFlags = resultData.getFlags();
                        takeFlags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        if(clipData != null){
                            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                                Uri dataUri = item.getUri();
                                if (dataUri != null) {
                                    uris.add(dataUri);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "File URI : " + dataUri.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            Uri dataUri = resultData.getData();
                            if (dataUri != null) {
                                uris.add(dataUri);
                            }
                        }
                        processFiles(uris);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to differentiate between png and jpeg. How can i achieve that ?

[Call `getType()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver?hl=en#getType(android.net.Uri)), passing in the `Uri`. This will return the MIME type associated with the content, such as `image/png`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Simple Storage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage) is much easier:

```java
MediaFile file = new MediaFile(context, uri);
String extension = file.getExtension();
```